# pdflatex/lualatex called from shutdown script can not find installed packages

Tags: bash, init.d, latex

At work I have set up a little backup script on my Ubuntu 14.04.1 machine. The script backs up my machine to an external hard drive. After this is done it copies a LaTeX project to my Dropbox and compiles it. This project is some kind of a logbook of my work.

I know this is a rather unconventional use case and I could just copy the source or push it to a git repo but first of all git would be a bit of an overkill and second of all there were already two instances where I was glad for having it in pdf form on my mobile when I had to start up a tty shell because gnome wouldn't start up.

The problem now is that for some reason both pdflatex and lualatex tell me that they can't find the `.sty` files. The backup script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

# .... some system backup code ....

## sync linux setup document to Dropbox
# remove .pdf in order to guarantee that project is compiled
rm /home/user/Documents/LaTeX/logBook/logBook.pdf
# compile project in origin 
make -C /home/user/Documents/LaTeX/logBook/ >> /home/user/Documents/LaTeX/logBook/makeLog
# copy files to destination
cp -rp /home/user/Documents/LaTeX/logBook/ /home/wright/Dropbox
```

And my `Makefile` contains the following lines:

```
SHELL=bash
TARGET=linuxSetup.pdf
FLAGS= --shell-escape
SRC= ./*.tex ./header/*.tex  ./chapters/*.tex ./references/*.bib ./titlepage/*.tex 
TIKZ= ./tikz/*.tex
LL= pdflatex


all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(TARGET:%.pdf=%.tex) $(SRC) $(TIKZ)
    @$(LL) $(FLAGS) $<
#   makeglossaries $(TARGET:%.pdf=%"")
#   makeindex -s headingsStyle.ist $(TARGET:%.pdf=%.idx)
#   bibtex $(TARGET:%.pdf=%"")
    @$(LL) $(FLAGS) $<
    @$(LL) $(FLAGS) $<
```

The backup script is placed in `/etc/init.d/backup` and contains a symbolic link to `/etc/rc0.d/S01Backup`.

The scripts are simple enough, yet they still won't find the `.sty` files. I tried excluding the `.sty` files to find out if the problem was caused by specific ones but regardless of how many I exclude there are always more that the compiler won't find. I switched the compiler yet that does not seem to be the issue either. And also I executed the complete backup script via `sudo` or as the root user, both of which worked perfectly fine without any errors.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**
Here is the last bit of the output:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cite/cite.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mh/empheq.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mh/mhsetup.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mh/mathtools.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/calc.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etex-pkg/etex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancybox/fancybox.sty
Style option: `fancybox' v1.4 <2010/05/15> (tvz)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty)

! LaTeX Error: File `floatflt.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

The `floatflt.sty` file in question is located in the texlive install directory `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/floatflt`. The other packages that it did find above, however, are located in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/<packagename>`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us the full paths of the sty files that aren't found. Are they in system directories or in your LaTeX project dir?

Comment: @terdon I added part of the output and the file locations above. It seems that the script does not find the packages located `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/` directory, doesn't it?

Comment: Where are you compiling? Is it on the same machine? Your scripts are only copying files from your project dir, so it doesn't touch the `.sty files. Does your project compile correctly in `/home/user/Documents/LaTeX/logBook/`? Are you compiling the Dropbox copy from another machine?

Comment: you can use `TEXINPUTS` var to hold place to look for input.

Comment: @terdon I am compiling on the same machine as the source and destination folders are, yes. Also I tried compiling directly from inside the source and from inside the destination folder, with no differences in behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two texlive installations. One by the system (Ubuntu) in `/usr/share/texlive/` and on user-installed in `/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex`.

In your shutdown script, the environment variables are not adapted, such that the wrong texlive installation is used.

Try to call `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex` directly
or adapt the `PATH` environment variable accordingly.

There were some license problems with `floatflt.sty` in the past.
This could be the reason, why it is not included in the texlive installation of Ubuntu. You could try to change to `wrapfig`.

Comment: That was indeed the cause, it seems that the folder `/usr/share/texlive` was a leftover from `apt-get remove`. With `apt-get purge` the folder was deleted. Do you know why this only affected this script when executed during shutdown? I did call it from my user, from the root user and also via `sudo`, this problem only appeared during the shutdown process, even though this script is called at the very beginning when this runlevel is entered...

Comment: @DavidWright The environment variables, especially PATH, could be different. Use something like `export >> /path/to/a/log/file` in your bash script to check them.